# Custom menu with different behavior for every item

Tags: menus

I'm working on a custom menu that is particularly complex and I like to know which is the right way to build it.

This is the structure of my menu:

```
- Home (is a PAGE)

- Information (Is a PAGE with a second level menu)
        |_________Items are the post for the category "information"

- Data (It hasn't a PAGE, only a second level menu)
        |_________Items are the posts for the category "data"
```

In your opinion which is the best way to build a menu like this? is it possible to build it from the WP backend or is better to create it just from code in the template?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this using the backend nav menu support, using classes as markers that are then picked via the `walker_nav_menu_start_el` filter ( which then do queries to grab posts and insert their markup )

e.g.

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'menu_show_media_post', 10, 4 );

function menu_show_media_post( $item_output = '', $item = '', $depth = '', $args = '' ) {
    global $post;

    $query = false;

    if ( is_array( $item->classes ) ) {

        foreach( $item->classes as $class ) {
            if ( $class == 'some_marker_class_to_watch_for_goes_here') {
                $query = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $query ) {
        $args = array(
        );
        $q = new WP_Query($args);
        if($q->have_posts()){
            while($q->have_posts()){
                $q->the_post();
                // do stuff and append output to $item_output, dont echo it out
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    return $item_output;
}
```

All in all this is a fairly advanced level thing to do.

If you want to go a step further you can add UI controls to the menu pull outs themselves, and store the data as post meta for each menu nav item. This would be a better way of doing it, but it's not for the faint of heart as it requires JS code in the admin backend, and a custom walker to render out the initial html for the nav admin interface.